# Is it possible to execute code for every fired event without too much boilerplate code?

Tags: magento2, php, module, event-observer, magento-1

This is mostly out of curiousity, as I think it would be very useful in some situations. Is there are a way in Magento to execute a piece of code every time an event is fired, regardless of the event?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Pretty sure there isn't a neat way of doing this. There's no built in mechanism and the only functions that would really allow you to inject the behaviour are `Mage_Core_Model_App::dispatchEvent` and `Mage_Core_Model_Config::getEventConfig`, neither of which can be rewritten.

Comment: Rewriting Mage_Core_Model_Config is possible, but you need to change `Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);` to `Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType, ['config_model' => 'New_Config_Model_Class']);` in `index.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all for your suggestions. With your suggestions nudging me into the right direction, I have figured out a way to do it:

```
$events = array_keys(Mage::app()->_events['global']);
```

`Mage_Core_Model_App` needs to be extended for this, however, as `$_events` is a protected property. Because my observer doesn't need to extend anything else, this seems to work quite well for most of my intended purposes.

This gives me an ordered array of the fired events until the last known dispatched event. With this knowledge, it's possible to bind logic to the patterns within. This is an example of the data that is returned within my `controller_front_send_response_after` observer:

```
array(45) {
    [0] => string(22) "resource_get_tablename"
    [1] => string(36) "core_collection_abstract_load_before"
    ...
    [43] => string(25) "http_response_send_before"
    [44] => string(36) "controller_front_send_response_after"
}
```

I'm not sure if I'm really happy with the lack of elegance and style, but it appears to do what it needs to do for now.

Comment: This will only give you events that already have an observer attached. If you want to react on every event, you need to rewrite `Mage_Core_Model_App::dispatchEvent` or `Mage_Core_Model_Config::getEventConfig()` (see here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/68594/is-it-possible-to-configure-one-event-observer-for-all-magento-events/73024#73024 )

Answer (score 2):

Try modifying Mage_Core_Model_App::dispatchEvent to: (untested!)

```
    public function dispatchEvent($eventName, $args)
    {
            if($eventName != 'onEventFired')
            {
                    $this->dispatchEvent('onEventFired', array('event' => $eventName));
            }

            foreach ($this->_events as $area=>$events) {
            ...
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! I've figured out a way to do it thanks to your nudging into the right direction. I've posted my own answer.

Answer (score 1):

See the dispatchEvent() function both in [here](http://doc-magento.com/nav.html?app/Mage.php.html#dispatchevent) and in [here](http://doc-magento.com/nav.html?app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php.html#dispatchevent). Maybe you can somehow override those functions and add your code. If you are looking for a "master event" i don't think that exists.

Comment: if dispatchEvent() automatically dispatches another event an infinite loop will occur :)

Comment: As with Mex, thanks for the suggestion. I have figured it out and posted my solution.