# Is it possible to configure one event Observer for all Magento events?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-enterprise, architecture

Is it possible (whether practical or not) to cut some configuration down by registering an observer to all Magento Events.

The purpose for this would be to build an Observer that works as a "service locator" plugin for a custom module.

I would want to do something like, but for all events:

```
 ...
 <events>
   <event_name>
     <observers>
       <mymodule_integration>
         <class>mymodule_integration/observer</class>
         <method>service_locator</method>
       </mymodule_integration>
      </observers>
    </event_name>
 </events>
 ...
```

And in the Observer:

```
 class My_Model_Observer
 {

    public function locateService(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
       $event = $observer->getEvent()->getName();

       // map (string) $event to (string) $model
       // .....

       if ($model && $event) {
           Mage::getModel(mymodule/$model)->$event;
       }

       return true;
     }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not believe this would be possible without making some rather unwise modifications. In any given action, Magento sends of observer events for a lot of actions based on before and after type events that are named dynamically.

I have not noticed any generic ones that would trigger on all circumstances, and in all honestly, even if there was a general always fires one the usefulness of it would be questionable - you likely would not have sufficient information to tell if your looking at a product load, customer save, block load, conversion or any other kind that happens.

```
public static function dispatchEvent($name, array $data = array())
{
    Varien_Profiler::start('DISPATCH EVENT:'.$name);
    $result = self::app()->dispatchEvent($name, $data);
    Varien_Profiler::stop('DISPATCH EVENT:'.$name);
    return $result;
}
```

You may wish to add some debug statements into this function in Mage.php then look at what you are trying to target. Perhaps there are some generic ones that will fire at high enough level for your precise requirements.

You may wish to also provide a bit more details as to what your actual objective is, do you really need it on all events?

Comment: I need to build services to external data actions for many events; and was thinking of possible ways to cut down on the number of configuration nodes and files to simplify adding new services - while essentially creating a plugin-able service locator for another module developer. In other words, I'm getting starting with Magento and looking for the best way to build reusable services for many events. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not out of the box but it should be possible with a rewrite of `Mage_Core_Model_Config::getEventConfig()` (untested code):

```
public function getEventConfig($area, $eventName)
{
    $configNode = parent::getEventConfig($area, $eventName);
    $globalObservers = $this->_eventAreas[$area]->all;
    foreach ($globalObservers->children() as $globalObserver) {
        $configNode->appendChild($globalObserver);
    }
    return $configNode;

}
```

Now you can add observers for the event `all` which will be added to all other events on the fly.

Comment: Actually, it's not so easy to append a subtree to another node in SimpleXml. Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418019/simplexml-append-one-tree-to-another for help with that line